# matTextareaAutosize overriding minimum row for Textarea

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-6

I have a textarea that I am trying to use matTextareaAutosize dynamically. I am using the buttons to change the showText value between true and false. However, it seems to be overriding the default rows being set with minRows. Now the default rows for the textarea is always 1. Is there a way assign default rows in a textarea with matTextareaAutosize being used?

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated

textarea component.html

```
   <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput
      class="descriptionText"
      minRows="3"
      [matTextareaAutosize]="showText"
      #description
      placeholder="{{ 'COLUMNS.description' | translate }}"
      formControlName="description"
      required>
    </textarea>
    <mat-error *ngIf="caseForm.invalid">{{ 'CASES.descriptionError' | translate }}</mat-error>
    <mat-hint align="end">{{description.value.length}} / 1000</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
      <div *ngIf="statusReason">
    <button mat-button (click)="resizeDescription(true)">Show More</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="resizeDescription(false)">Show Less</button>
  </div>
```

component.ts

```
  resizeDescription(value: boolean) {
   this.showText = value;
  }
```

Comment: A late reply, but did you try cdkAutosizeMinRows="3"?